# WPF RoutedCommand/RoutedEvent who/what raises the event?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events, routed-commands

I'm trying to understand how WPF implements the routed commands which, internally, are themselves implemented by routed events. In the `UIElement` class definition, we find this piece of code:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(type, CommandDevice.CommandDeviceEvent, new 
    CommandDeviceEventHandler(UIElement.OnCommandDeviceThunk), false);
```

From there on, the `UIElement.OnCommandDeviceThunk` handler will pass along all the information through arguments of functions it calls in its body which themselves do the same until it reaches the `CommandBinding.Executed` event which we subscribe to, thus executing our response code.

What I can't seem to find, and would like to understand, is who raises the `CommandDevice.CommandDeviceEvent`?

When, for example, I have linked a `ButtonBase` subclass object's `Command` property to an ApplicationCommands command, does it raise the `CommandDeviceEvent` in some way and how does it do it?

I understand the `GlobalEventManager` holds scores of lists of event handlers, but I haven't yet understood who raises the events to trigger those handlers?

Answer (score 2):

> When, for example, I have linked a `ButtonBase` subclass object's `Command` property to an ApplicationCommands command, does it raise the `CommandDeviceEvent` in some way and how does it do it?

The `ButtonBase` class calls the `ExecuteCommandSource` method of an internal `CommandHelpers` class when it is clicked: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,c0949dd81fca07f3,references

This method then executes the actual command, i.e. the object that the `ICommand` property returns: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Commands/CommandHelpers.cs,518e4547841e704d